# Linux can't find file that exists

Tags: 64-bit, arch-linux

I'm trying to get Google's Dart language up and running, but it errors when running dart2js.  I'm running Arch linux and I installed [dart-sdk](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=57488) from AUR.  Some relevant terminal output lies below.

```
% dart2js main.dart   
/usr/local/bin/dart2js: line 7: /usr/local/bin/dart: No such file or directory

% cat /usr/local/bin/dart2js
#!/bin/sh
# Copyright (c) 2012, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
# for details. All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
# BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

BIN_DIR=`dirname $0`
exec $BIN_DIR/dart --allow_string_plus=false $BIN_DIR/../lib/dart2js/lib/compiler/implementation/dart2js.dart "$@"

% file /usr/local/bin/dart                                                                                          
/usr/local/bin/dart: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), 
dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15,
BuildID[sha1]=0x27fe166ca015c1adfeaf3a6f9c018e7d7af46d9f, stripped

% ls -alh /usr/local/bin
total 4.9M
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Jun 10 22:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root 4.0K Jun 10 22:51 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 422K May 10 22:41 cargo
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 2.7M Jun 10 22:50 dart
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  360 Jun  6 16:20 dart2js
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  176 Jun  6 16:20 pub
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 166K May 10 22:41 rustc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 1.6M May 10 22:41 rustdoc

% uname -rm
3.3.7-1-ARCH x86_64
```

Could it be because I'm running a 64bit OS and the dart binary is 32bit?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In order to execute an ELF binary linux needs to start a program that decodes ELF, loads dynamic libraries, etc. This program is called *program interpreter*. The name and full path to the program interpreter is written in the ELF itself

For instance

```
 $ file /usr/bin/cheese 
 /usr/bin/cheese: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386

 $ readelf -l /usr/bin/cheese  
 Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
 ...
 Program Headers:
 ...
 INTERP         0x000154 0x08048154 0x08048154 0x00013 0x00013 R   0x1
  [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.2]
 ...
```

If the program interpreter requested by the ELF is not found BASH gets the file not found error and reports "No such file or directory".

As @poige said above, you need to install basic support for running 32-bit applications.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Arch x86_64 doesn't come with 32-bit apps support by default. See this:

«… [Can I run 32-bit apps inside Arch64?](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch64_FAQ#Can_I_run_32-bit_apps_inside_Arch64.3F) […] You can install lib32-* libraries from the multilib repository …»